# Add items to SPO with Azure Automation runbook

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, azure-automation, azure-runbook

I want to add an item to a list in SharePoint Online using a runbook in Azure Automation.
Add an item as below, but the message "Push notification function is not active on site 'https://[tenantID].sharepoint.com/sites/[sitename]'" appears and I cannot add it.
If you execute the same command in local PowerShell, you can add items, but I do not know the cause, so please let me know.
Sorry for your inconvenience.

`
$Credential = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name 'admin'
$SiteUrl = "https://[tenantID].sharepoint.com/sites/[sitename]"
Connect-PnPOnline –Url $SiteUrl –Credentials (Get-Credential -Credential $Credential)

Add-PnPListItem -List $ListName -Values @{"Title" = "TestTitle";"ID" = "TestID";"Message" = "TestMessage";}
`

Answer (score 0):

Where are credentials stored? I do recommend to store them in Azure KeyVault.
Here is sameple script

```
$login=(Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName "" -Name "").SecretValueText
$password=(Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName "" -Name "").SecretValueText
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($login, $secpasswd)
$url=""
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $url -Credentials $mycreds
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.
Until now, it was saved in "Automation Account> Shared Resources> Credentials".
Changed to save and execute in Azure Key Vault.
But I am still getting the same error.
Do you know the solution?

Comment: Try to run same script from you local machine, does it works? Did you enable feature menthioned in previous answer?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a try this solution to fix the error:

```
Connect-PnPOnline https:/ /mytenant.sharepoint.com

Enable-PnPFeature -Identity 41e1d4bf-b1a2-47f7-ab80-d5d6cbba3092
```

BR